# Regex JSON response Gatling stress tool

Tags: regex, json, scala, http, gatling

Wanting to capture a variable called scanNumber in the http response loking like this:

```
{"resultCode":"SUCCESS","errorCode":null,"errorMessage":null,"profile":{"fullName":"TestFirstName TestMiddleName TestLastName","memberships":[{"name":"UA Gold Partner","number":"123-456-123-123","scanNumber":"123-456-123-123"}]}}
```

How can I do this with a regular experssion?
The tool I am using is Gatling stress tool (with the Scala DSL)

I have tried to do it like this:

```
.check(jsonPath("""${scanNumber}""").saveAs("scanNr")))
```

But I get the error:

```
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> Check extractor resolution crashed: No attribute named 'scanNu      5 (100,0%)
mber' is defined
```

Answer (score 4):

You were close first time.

What you actually want is:

```
.check(jsonPath("""$..scanNumber""").saveAs("scanNr")))
```

or possibly:

```
.check(jsonPath("""$.profile.memberships[0].scanNumber""").saveAs("scanNr")))
```

Note that this uses jsonPath, not regular expressions. JsonPath should more reliable than regex for this.

Check out the [JsonPath spec](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for more advanced usage.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex to match this in anywhere in json:

```
/"scanNumber":"[^"]+"/
```

and if you want to match just happens in structure you said use:

```
/\{[^{[]+\{[^{[]+\[\{[^{[]*("scanNumber":"[^"]+")/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since json fields may change its order you should make your regex more tolerant for those changes:

```
val j = """{"resultCode":"SUCCESS","errorCode":null,"errorMessage":null,"profile":{"fullName":"TestFirstName TestMiddleName TestLastName","memberships":[{"name":"UA Gold Partner","number":"123-456-123-123","scanNumber":"123-456-123-123"}]}}"""
val scanNumberRegx = """\{.*"memberships":\[\{.*"scanNumber":"([^"]*)".*""".r
val scanNumberRegx(scanNumber) = j

scanNumber //String = 123-456-123-123
```

This will work even if the json fields will be in different order (but of course keep the structure)